# Microsoft TeamsFx - Integrate API Connection with your Teams app?

Tags: bots, connection, microsoft-teams

I am currently following this **Microsoft TeamsFx** tutorial on how to integrate an API connection with my Teams app: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/Integrate-API-Connection-with-your-Teams-app#step-1-add-sdk-to-project.

I am on **Step 2: Provide ApiClient for project ** and am trying the **Basic Auth** option.

Where in my project hierarchy would I place this sample code?

```
**const teamsfxSdk = require("@microsoft/teamsfx");

// Initialize a new axios instance to call your API
const authProvider = new teamsfxSdk.BasicAuthProvider(
  process.env.TEAMSFX_API_USERNAME,
  process.env.TEAMSFX_API_PASSWORD
);
const apiClient = teamsfxSdk.createApiClient(
  process.env.TEAMSFX_API_ENDPOINT,
  authProvider
);
module.exports.apiClient = apiClient;**
```

I have tried looking at the documentation but it doesn't specify where I should place the code.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be placed in a new file within the bot or api folder of your project. This file is typically named `{your_api_alias}.js` or `{your_api_alias}.ts` based on your preference for JavaScript or TypeScript.

After creating this file, you can import the API client in any part of your application that needs to make requests to the API.
For example:

```
import {yourApiClient} from '{relative path to the generated file}'
```

This will allow you to use the yourApiClient to make requests to your API.

Comment: Thank you!

I was informed that I would be using OAuth 2 authentication instead. 

Would that involve the Custom Auth Implementation method?

If so, how would I implement that?

Comment: Please refer: https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/  Sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-auth/nodejs